# how to include editorial work in list of publications

Tags: publications, editors

Is there an acceptable way to include editorial work on journal articles in my list of publications?

Comment: What kind of editorial work do you mean?

Comment: On your own articles (but why?), other people's articles (then you might be mentioned in the acknowledgments), or do you mean reviewing papers for journals?

Answer (score 1):

Contributions such as editorial work must go under "Scientific and Academic Activities" in a CV and not under "Publications", because for it to be posted under "Publications" one must be an author on that publication (which editors are not).

Comment: Or it could be called "Service"